# Writing a search filter -- filter at the SQL level or PHP level?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an ajax filter on a search page that filters teacher results based on a set of criteria that can be manipulated by the user. I'm trying to decide whether to

1) first go get all the teachers data, then in PHP make a new array of just those teachers who aren't affected by the negative filters

or

2) build an sql query with a number of WHERE clauses, i.e. 'WHERE pay = $pay && city = $city && distance < $distance".

Part of me thinks that number 2 might be a better option, but I'm already unsure of how to fill the query's variable values when the user hasn't specified a certain filter. So, for example, if $pay is undefined, the query will fail. in this case, what I would like to do is query teachers regardless of their pay.

Comment: Hands down, SQL in any dedicated db is going to do a better job over even moderate sets, especially if you have a good set of indices.

Answer (score 0):

For the SQL approach, you should build your query based on whether or not the inputs are empty

Something like

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Teachers';
$filter = array();
if (!empty($pay)) $filter[] = 'pay = "'.$pay.'"';
if (!empty($city)) $filter[] = 'city = "'.$city.'"';
if (!empty($city)) $filter[] = 'distance < "'.$distance.'"';

if (!empty($filter)) {
    $and = ' WHERE';
    foreach ($filter as $f) {
        $sql .= $and.' '.$f;
        $and = ' AND';
    }
}
```

Mind you, you should be concerned about SQL injection since this is just a simple demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a lot of teachers in the database you can fetch all of them and handle it in PHP as you suggested.

If you don't want to fetch a lot of data you can go with the second option. In that case you might want to build a dynamic query.

for example:

```
$payCond = "";

... 

if (isset($pay) && $pay != ""){
    if ($payCond != ""){
        $payCond .= "And ";
    }
    $payCond = "pay=" . intval($pay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Query as close to the database as possible.  That said, you can use vacuous expressions to simplify code:

```
$payExpr = (isset($_REQUEST['pay']) ? 'pay='.$_REQUEST['pay'] : '1=1');
$query = "select * from Foo where $payExpr";
```

The secret sauce here is using '1=1' when pay not given.  However, there is still more you need to do that I'm skipping in this quick example, like avoiding sql injection with bound parameters.  Caveat emptor: I havent compiled this code, as I am pecking on a tablet!